# Merge and Overwrite datasets in pig

Tags: hadoop, join, merge, apache-pig

I have 3 sets of data all in the format (acctid:chararray, rule:chararray, value:charrarray)

Set 1 file:

```
123;R1;r1 version set 1 123
123;R2;r2 version set 1 123
123;R3;r3 version set 1 123
124;R1;r1 version set 1 124
124;R2;r2 version set 1 124
124;R3;r3 version set 1 124
```

Set 2 file: // changes R2

```
123;R2;r2 version set 2 123
124;R2;r2 version set 2 124
```

Set 3 file:

```
123;R4;r4 version set 3 123
124;R4;r4 version set 3 124
```

I need to merge the data such that:

- in the first data set, the R2 values get changed to those from the second set
- R3 values get removed
- R4 values get added

Then I can do a group by account id and get:

final:

```
123;R1;r1 version set 1 123
123;R2;r2 version set 2 123
123;R4;r4 version set 3 123
124;R1;r1 version set 1 124
124;R2;r2 version set 2 124
124;R4;r4 version set 3 124
```

I tried various joins and merges but I don't understand if this is even possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will give desired output

```
set_1 = LOAD '/home/abhis/set_1' USING PigStorage(';') AS (acctid:chararray, rule: chararray, value: chararray);
set_2 = LOAD '/home/abhis/set_2' USING PigStorage(';') AS (acctid:chararray, rule: chararray, value: chararray);
set_3 = LOAD '/home/abhis/set_3' USING PigStorage(';') AS (acctid:chararray, rule: chararray, value: chararray);


DATA_SET1 = FILTER set_1 BY (rule matches '.*R1.*');

DATA_SET2 = UNION DATA_SET1,set_2,set_3;
DATA_SET3 = ORDER DATA_SET2 by acctid,rule;
dump DATA_SET3;
```

Output

```
(123,R1,r1 version set 1 123)
(123,R2,r2 version set 2 123)
(123,R4,r4 version set 3 123)
(124,R1,r1 version set 1 124)
(124,R2,r2 version set 2 124)
(124,R4,r4 version set 3 124)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good approach, is it possible to somehow do a matches on say more than one value, basically I have a string of Rvalues separated by commas and need to filter out anything that is not in there from the records. it is passed in as a string and I can't get the tokenize to work on it.